# ios NSXMLParserDelegate isn't doing anything

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse a xml file by calling an `NSObject` class where I have my parser. But, when I call the method to start the parse process it doesn't do anything:

from my view controller implementation:

```
ParseXml *parser=[[ParseXml alloc]init];
[parser loadXmlToParse];
```

my ParseXml header:

```
 @interface ParseXml : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

my ParseXml implementation:

```
-(void)loadXmlToParse
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myXMLFile" withExtension:@"xml"];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [parser parse];
}
```

The method `loadXmlToParse` is being called but after it's been called it just doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Is the `NSXMLParser` actually getting created or is it nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
-(void)loadXmlToParse
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myXMLFile" withExtension:@"xml"];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
   parser.delegate = self;
   [parser parse];
}
```

You forgot to assign the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this line:

parser.delegate=self;